# Quantum tunneling wave function derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, universe

In Vilenkin's paper Quantum cosmology and the initial state of the Universe, We find the tunneling wave function to be $ \psi _{T}=\frac{Ai(-z)+iBi(-z)}{Ai(-z_{0})+iBi(-z_{0})}$ (4.27 in the original paper) where $z=-(2V)^{-2/3}(1-a^{2}V) $ in the scalar field case . Then he says that we can write $\psi_{T}=e^{i\pi /4}(a^{2}V-1)^{-1/4}\exp\left (-\frac{1+i(a^{2}V-1)^{3/2}}{3V}\right )\,for\, (a^{2}V>1)$ and $ \psi_{T}=(1-a^{2}V)^{-1/4}\exp\left (\frac{(1-a^{2}V)^{3/2}-1}{3V}\right ) \,for\,(a^{2}V<1)$.(4.30 and 4.31 in the original paper) I am having trouble to work out how he derived this from the asymptotic form? Could anyone gives some detailed derivation?

Vilenkin, A. (1988). Quantum cosmology and the initial state of the Universe. Phys. Rev. D, 37, 888–897.

Comment: Are you familiar with the asymptotic expansion of $Ai$ and $Bi$?

Comment: Yes. and it is given in the paper. But I got a wrong answer and struggle to find out why.